# CodeIgniter Authentication Error - NOT READING FROM DATABASE

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm abit of a newbie to PHP so I've come here so you experts might be able to help me out. I've been having strange problem in where I was previously able to login into my system, the session was recorded into the database. All of a sudden I cannot login no matter what I try to do. I am sure I have a syntax error somewhere but here is my code.

**Model:**

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function check_login($action="view"){
        $user_data=$this->session->userdata('user_data');
        if(!$this->session->userdata('user_data')||!isset($user_data[$this->control_name."_".$action])){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Oops you do not have access to the requested page ..!');
            redirect("staff_accounts/login");
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function login(){

    $username=$this->input->post("username");
    $password=$this->input->post("password");

    if($this->input->post("btn_login")){
        $password=($password!=NULL)?md5(trim($password)):NULL;

        if($username==NULL||$username=='')
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Username is required!');
        else if($password==NULL||$password=='')
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Password is required!');
        else
        {
            $sql=sprintf("select a.*,r.* from ".TBL_STAFF_ACCOUNTS." a  inner join ".TBL_RANKS." r on r.id=a.rank_id where a.staff_id='%s'",$username);

            $user=$this->db->query($sql)->row_array();

            if($user!=NULL && $this->encrypt->decode($user['password'])==$password)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome <em>'.$user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name'].'!</em>');

                $permissions=(array)json_decode($user['permissions']);
                unset($user['permissions']);

                $user=array_merge($permissions,$user);
                $this->session->set_userdata("user_data",$user);

                redirect("dashboard"); 
            }
            else
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Username login failed...<em>User not found!</em>');
            }
        }
        $this->data['title']   = 'User login '.CIBB_TITLE;
        $this->load->view('_LoginHeader', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('staff_accounts/login');
        $this->load->view('_LoginFooter');  
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: please mention your output or error you are getting....!!

Comment: no matter what credentials I use to log in, when i hit the log in button it just refreshes and tells me 'Username login failed...User not found!

Comment: Code does not break all by itself.  What changes did you make just before this stopped working?

Comment: I cleaned up your Controller code's indentation so it's easier to read.... but what an odd mix of Allman, 1TBS, and skipping braces altogether.   At least be consistent with your coding style so problems will be easier to see.